# Read text file, save all digits into character string

Tags: c, file, input

I am trying to read a text file containing the string "a3rm5t?7!z*&gzt9v" and put all the numeric characters into a character string to later convert into an integer.

I am currently trying to do this by using sscanf on the buffer after reading the file, and then using sprintf to save all characters found using %u in a character string called str.

However, the integer that is returning when I call printf on str is different each time I run the program. What am I doing right and what am I doing wrong?

This code works when the text file contains a string like "23dog" and returns 23 but not when the string is something like 23dog2.

EDIT: I now realize that i should be putting the numeric characters in a character ARRAY rather than just one string.

```
int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
    int in;
    char buffer[128];
    char *str;
    FILE *input;

    in = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    read(in, buffer, 128);

    unsigned x;
    sscanf(buffer, "%u", &x);
    sprintf(str,"%u\n", x);
    printf("%s\n",str);

    close (in);

    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken, sprintf with %u ends reading input after first nonnumeric character. You should create a number only string before converting to an integer

Comment: Judging by the output I got in my last paragraph i would have to agree. Is there a way to still use sscanf in a while loop or something to counteract this?

Comment: When you have done it and you want to check the result, you can use `echo 'a3rm5t?7!z*&gzt9v' | tr -dc [0-9]`

Comment: You are passing a dangling pointer to `sprintf`.  Furthermore, the passed pointer is the same every time.  Do you mean to (partially) overwrite the previous result?  Finally, for `23dog2`, do you expect `232` or something else?

Comment: Yes, I would expect 232 for 23dog2 and 3579 in the string I mentioned at the beginning of my post. I am meaning to read each character separately in the input file and append each number to a character array.

Comment: Then why not do away with all those `scanf`s and `sprintf`s and simply loop over the buffer copying over any character `c` if `c >= '0' && c <= '9'`?

Comment: 5gon, I am appending your suggestion the the end of my code because I am not sure how it would work. Would the code I posted be able to loop through the buffer the way you are suggesting?

Comment: Using `scanf()` is probably the wrong tool for the given job.  Using `getchar()` along with `isdigit()` from `<ctype.h>` would make more sense.  Make sure pointers and array indexes are initialized appropriately.  If you do use `scanf()`, you probably have to get adventuresome with conversion specifications such as `%*[^0-9]` and `%n`.

Comment: @Broaj I have made my comment an answer.  Hope it makes sense for you.  If the `if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')` confuses you, cou can also use `isdigit` as @JonathanLeffler suggested.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to filter out any non-digits from your input, you need not use `scanf`, `sprintf` and the like.  Simply loop over the buffer and copy the characters that are digits.

The following program only works for a single line of input read from standard input and only if it is less than 512 characters long but it should give you the correct idea.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 512

int
main()
{
  char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];  /* Here we read into. */
  char digits[BUFFER_SIZE];  /* Here we insert the digits. */
  char * pos;
  size_t i = 0;
  /* Read one line of input (max BUFFER_SIZE - 1 characters). */
  if (!fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, stdin))
    {
      perror("fgets");
      return 1;
    }
  /* Loop over the (NUL terminated) buffer. */
  for (pos = buffer; *pos; ++pos)
    {
      if (*pos >= '0' && *pos <= '9')
        {
          /* It's a digit: copy it over. */
          digits[i++] = *pos;
        }
    }
  digits[i] = '\0';  /* NUL terminate the string. */
  printf("%s\n", digits);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand the code better though i was able to modify it to accept a text file. it looks like we set pos to be equal to the buffer, then iterate through the buffer and if the next character is a digits it is pointedto the digits array. The i++ in the brackets keep iterating digits to 1,2,3, etc. What exactly does null terminating the string and fgets do?

Comment: @Broaj Almost exactly, except that it is of course not “pointed to the digits array” but rather *copied* to it.  NUL terminating the string simply means appending a NUL byte at the end so `printf` knows where the string ends.  `fgets` reads one line from a file and stores it into a buffer (if the buffer is large enough, else, the line is truncated).  See the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) for more info.  Using `fgets` is not essential here, you can read the file however it is most convenient for you.

Answer (score 0):

A good approach to any problem like this is to read the **entire line** into a `buffer` and then assign a `pointer` to the `buffer`. You can then use the pointer to step through the buffer reading each character and acting on it appropriately. The following is one example of this approach. `getline` is used to read the line from the file (it has the advantage of allocating space for `buffer` and returning the number of characters read). You then allocate space for the character string based on the size of buffer as returned by `getline`. Remember, when done, you are responsible for freeing the memory allocated by `getline`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, const char **argv)
{
    char *buffer = NULL;    /* forces getline to allocate required space    */
    ssize_t read = 0;       /* number of characters read by getline         */
    size_t n = 0;           /* limit of characters to read, (0 no limit)    */
    char *str = NULL;       /* string to hold digits read from file         */
    char *p = NULL;         /* ptr to use with buffer (could use buffer)    */
    int idx = 0;            /* index for adding digits to str               */
    int number = 0;         /* int to hold number parsed from file          */
    FILE *input;

    /* validate input */
    if (argc < 2) { printf ("Error: insufficient input. Usage: %s filename\n", argv[0]); return 1; }

    /* open and validate file */
    input = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (!input) { printf ("Error: failed to open file '%s\n", argv[1]); return 1; }

    /* read line from file with getline */
    if ((read = getline (&buffer, &n, input)) != -1)
    {
        str = malloc (sizeof (char) * read);    /* allocate memory for str      */
        p = buffer;                             /* set pointer to buffer        */
        while (*p)                              /* read each char in buffer     */
        {
            if (*p > 0x2f && *p < 0x3a)         /* if char is digit 0-9         */
            {
                str[idx] = *p;                  /* copy to str at idx           */
                idx++;                          /* increment idx                */
            }
            p++;                                /* increment pointer            */
        }
        str[idx] = 0;                           /* null-terminate str           */

        number = atoi (str);                    /* convert str to int           */

        printf ("\n string : %s number : %d\n\n", buffer, number);

    } else {
        printf ("Error: nothing read from file '%s\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    if (input)  fclose (input);                 /* close input file stream          */
    if (buffer) free (buffer);                  /* free memory allocated by getline */
    if (str)    free (str);                     /* free memory allocated to str     */

    return 0;
}
```

**datafile:**

```
$ cat dat/fwintstr.dat
a3rm5t?7!z*&gzt9v
```

**output:**

```
$ ./bin/prsint dat/fwintstr.dat

 string : a3rm5t?7!z*&gzt9v
 number : 3579
```

Comment: Nice work.  I wanted to avoid allocating dynamic memory in my answer since it adds additional complexity and the OP originally also did without it.  I must say that among the tests `c > 0x2f && c < 0x3a`, `c >= '0' && c <= '9'` and `isdigit(c)`, I find the first the least readable.

Comment: Another favorite is `c > '/' && c < ':'` or `c > 47 && c < 58`. The intent is simply to avoid the initial character conversion. I've also seen it expressed as bit-shifts. I agree though -- readability is key. It should be properly coded as `c >= '0' && c <= '9'`. However, sometimes, the little nuggets of learning are sprinkled in, just for that purpose and not by accident :)